# Should APIs send back UI layer text/data in API response to allow changes anytime in older android/ios app versions?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, api-design

Should the (title of various android/ios screens, labels of various form-controls) be hardcoded in android/ios apps OR such data should be brought from the API responsei?

Most of the page/section-of-page has a title. In form with textbox/combo box, we have labels for each of these controls as well. Should such UI information be hard-coded OR brought from the API?

Few questions here:

1. Pros of having all this hard-coded on android/ios apps: Clean and light weight API data. APIs will carry only the data part and not the user-interface elements like title, labels etc. This would save bandwidth and make APIs bit fast.
2. Cons of having all this hard-coded on android/ios apps: If we want to change these title, labels in future, we can only do that on the newer version. All previous app version will continue to show the old title/labels only. If we had brought this data from APIs, we can change these anytime across all the versions.

Which is correct approach? Or should we decide this based on the fact if titles/labels can change in future and they need to be changed for all app versions, if this is the case, then it should be in API otherwise they could be hard coded?
Can Apps use firebase to get such information and change it in previous app versions too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should Web API response just contain the data OR data with User Interface things for future flexibility on android and ios clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172966/should-web-api-response-just-contain-the-data-or-data-with-user-interface-things)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably not be a very good user experience to populate all of the UI elements from API calls without at least having some hardcoded defaults in place to allow the user to initially navigate within the app without waiting for the API calls to retrieve information. Also, if you try to create an app using this server-side UI design you probably want to use mostly web components and possibly even serve up the html to the app because there can be a mismatch between the content (i.e. the text for the labels, buttons, and text fields) and the UI elements themselves. For example, imagine a segmented control that initially was designed to only accommodate two options ("Home" and "Work") and then later an additional text option is added to the list ("Home," "Work" and "Gym").